# Msal.js iframe issue with twitter and while choosing from multiple google account

Tags: iframe, azure-ad-msal

I was going through [AzureAD msal library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) for javascript. I tried to run the [test app](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/devApps/VanillaJSTestApp-b2c) given in the same github link.

The app runs smoothly with facebook or microsoft account login. But when I try to login with twitter, it throws the following error:

```
Refused to display 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=....' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://tweetdeck.twitter.com https://tdapi-staging.smf1.twitter.com https://tdapi-staging.atla.twitter.com https://tweetdeck.localhost.twitter.com".
```

Also, the example works well when I have a **single google account** logged-in in my browser or when I enter google credential on the google login page. But when I have multiple google accounts logged-in and choose one of them for the app, it throws the following error:

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?.....' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

In both the cases (twitter and multiple google accounts), the login happens, id token is generated but it fails to get access_token using `acquireTokenSilent()` and throws the above mentioned error. Then because of the `acquireTokenpopup()`, the login popup window shows again and when I enter my same credentials again, I get the access_token.

I have tried using `loginRedirect()` & `acquireTokenRedirect()` instead of popup but I have seen the same behavior.

What I have understood so far:

In the error cases, iframe is trying to add the google/twitter link into iframe src in the app home page (which is obviously not allowed).

In case of successful acquiring of access_token, I saw the iframe src has a microsoft login link (https://login.microsoftonline.com ...).

Can somebody help me understand why is it happening? And if someone has got a way to solve this, please help me out.

I haven't changed anything in the code, I just wanted to understand how msal.js works so that I can implement it in another project.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this? Almost two years later, this is still a problem...

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/177

Comment: I'm facing the same problem today